# routing / NATing 2 VPNs with iptables

Tags: iptables, vpn, iproute

Here is my setup:

```
Internet - router - Unix router - VPN1
                                - VPN2

router: 192.168.2.1/24
Unix router: 192.168.2.55/24
VPN1: 10.0.1.0/24 (Unix router: 10.0.1.10)
VPN2: 10.0.2.0/24 (Unix router: 10.0.2.10)
```

Whatever I try, I keep getting some packets being misdirected on one VPN or the other, or even through the direct connection.  I tried using connmark without success.

The default outgoing connection from my Unix router needs to be through the direct connection, not the VPNs.

I also would like to be able to get some traffic directed from either VPNs to my Unix router.  That's where it gets complicated to control the reverse path correctly.

It doesn't matter if the VPN servers have access to the 192.168.2.0/24 LAN but it would be a nice to have.

Can anyone point me in the right direction using `iptables` or `iproute2`?

Here is my current results with OpenVPN's `iroute` option set:

```
 # ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 brd 127.255.255.255 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp4s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1b:21:4e:3d:8a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp4s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1b:21:4e:3d:8b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:23:54:27:2b:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::223:54ff:fe27:2bc5/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:23:54:27:2b:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.55/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::223:54ff:fe27:2bc5/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:7d:a4:f6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe7d:a4f6/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: vnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:41:24:60 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe41:2460/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
18: tun2: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none
    inet 10.0.2.10 peer 10.0.2.1/32 scope global tun2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
19: tun1: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none
    inet 10.0.1.10 peer 10.0.1.1/32 scope global tun1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

 # ip route
default via 192.168.2.1 dev br0  metric 5
10.0.1.0/24 via 10.0.1.1 dev tun1
10.0.1.0/24 via 10.0.2.1 dev tun2
10.0.1.1 dev tun1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.1.10
10.0.2.0/24 via 10.0.1.1 dev tun1
10.0.2.0/24 via 10.0.2.1 dev tun2
10.0.2.1 dev tun2  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.10
104.223.87.195 via 192.168.2.1 dev br0
192.168.2.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.55
204.44.85.107 via 192.168.2.1 dev br0
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the setup (the VPNs are not something behind the Unix router), but the "how can I use several internet connections at once" question is a FAQ. With existing IP protocols, you can't. So whatever your setup is, use a single VPN to connect to the Internet, and put the VPN software on some device between the Internet and your internal network, e.g. the Unix router.

Comment: And if the VPNs just to connect to two private networks somewhere else, you don't need iptables, just set up the correct route.

Comment: @dirkt:  There are other machines and VMs involved in the whole setup and I've been able to get it to work at 95% by different means but I can't seem to fully solve it other than using a bridge which I'd like to avoid because of the layer 2 traffic generated.  If you know how to set up the route properly, could you please provide more insight into it?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Software like OpenVPN should set up the routes automatically. Please edit question with output of `ip addr` and `ip route` after starting the VPN tunnels, and describe what exactly you have done with "different means".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start off, my main problem was with `net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter` and `net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter` which need to be set at `2`.  See `/etc/sysctl.conf` to change it and use `sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf` to apply the change live.

That said, the full solution to control the return traffic is to first track the connections with `connmark`:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m mark ! --mark 0x0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i tun1 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x1
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i tun2 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x2
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -j CONNMARK --save-mark
```

Then you need to set up policy based routes.  You should define two new routing tables in `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` such as:

```
101     VPN1
102     VPN2
```

Then do routes for both directions in each table.  In my case, the VPN client IPs I get are `10.0.1.10` and `10.0.2.10`, and my local network interface is `192.168.2.55`.  So I do:

```
ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.2.55 table VPN1
ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.2.55 table VPN2
```

Then set the rule to follow those tables based on the mark set:

```
ip rule add fwmark 1 table VPN1
ip rule add fwmark 2 table VPN2
```

Finally, in my VPN's `upscript.sh`, I set the default gateway with:

```
ip route add default via 10.0.1.1 table VPN1
```

.. for VPN1, and

```
ip route add default via 10.0.2.1 table VPN2
```

.. for VPN2.

If you want the VPN servers to be able to route traffic directly to your LAN, you need to use, with OpenVPN, the `iroute` instruction for that client on each server (`ccd/client`) and also add that route entry in its configuration file ('openvpnserver.conf`).

Now start your VPNs and the traffic should always go back where it came in, as it has to.

Note that it would have been possible to reverse masquerade on the VPN servers, but that would hide the source IP which was not acceptable to me at all.